# Could not find androidsdk.modules

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

So in the middle of running my program, my build.gradle failed with this error. I mean it actually worked a second before, and not a second after. I changed nothing in my gradle.

```
Could not find androidsdk.modules:shield:unspecified.
Required by:
    project :app > com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.15.2
    project :app > com.facebook.android:facebook-core:5.15.2
    project :app > com.facebook.android:facebook-common:5.15.2
Search in build.gradle files
```

Here is my gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.example.casualdatingapp"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable "ResourceType"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:19.0.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jakob-grabner:Circle-Progress-View:1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.3.2'

    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    implementation "com.yuyakaido.android:card-stack-view:2.3.4"
    implementation 'org.mongodb:stitch-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.mindorks:placeholderview:0.7.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
    implementation 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.edmodo:rangebar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    def nav_version = "2.1.0"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

I don't know how or why this happened. Reverting to a previous git repo that worked didn't change anything... What could possibly be the issue?

Comment: Having the exact same problem building from Unity. Only happened today. Perhaps a remote repo has been moved? Very strange stuff.

Comment: @Zwander Do you know if it was a Facebook API issue?

Comment: same problem, I was about to open it myself. I'm using react-native and I tried to update to the latest version, no luck so far, I'm gonna leave it a few hours...

Comment: @AndrewYoung Yes, exact same version too, 5.15.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This fixed it for me. Only started happening today.

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.3'
```

Comment: it worked for me. the error have just happen today when opening my project

Comment: It also worked for me. I don't know how

Answer (score 3):

I should have mentioned that this solution works for React Native. Rob's solution is best for native Android.

---

I just now had the same problem and here's what worked for me. Add `facebookSdkVersion = "5.15.3"` to

```
android
|--build.gradle
```

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 18
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        ...

        // This is a temporary fix for react-native-fbsdk v1.1.2
        facebookSdkVersion = "5.15.3"
    }
}
```

References:

- https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/673
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/701

Comment: This didn't work for me, although the solution suggested by Rob did.

Answer (score 3):

We can config 3 thing about the facebook SDK to a react native Android app:

1. Version lib in `package.json`.
2. Dependency on `android/app/build.gradle`
3. Facebook sdk version on  `android/build.gradle`.

This errors is probably a bug: https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/701

For me work this config:

1. `"react-native-fbsdk": "1.1.2",` in package.json
2. `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,5.11.1)'` on android/app/build.gradle.
3. `facebookSdkVersion = '5.15.3'` in android/build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the same error when I try to build a project in Unity.

For Unity solved replacing the implementations to:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:[5,5.11.1)' 
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[5,5.11.1)' 
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,5.11.1)' 
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[5,5.11.1)'
```

in the Gradle template.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i just replaced my dependency with

`implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.3'`

and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a lot of people are having this issue, and the workaround is to override the **facebookSdkVersion** in react-native-fssdk android's build.gradle.

If you run this command on the terminal at your project root directory

```
cat node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build.gradle
```

you should see that this build gradle will check if there is variable defined from ext called **facebookSdkVersion**, if there is one, it will grab this for facebook.android library version.

```
def FACEBOOK_SDK_VERSION = safeExtGet('facebookSdkVersion', '[5.0,6.0[')

dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.facebook.android:facebook-core:${FACEBOOK_SDK_VERSION}"
    implementation "com.facebook.android:facebook-login:${FACEBOOK_SDK_VERSION}"
    implementation "com.facebook.android:facebook-share:${FACEBOOK_SDK_VERSION}"
}
```

According to github tickets [673](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/673) and [701](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/701), version 5.15.1 or 5.15.3 will fix this issue. So to override the **facebookSdkVersion**, you will define this in your project's android build.gradle like this.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 18
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        ...

        // the override version
        facebookSdkVersion = "5.15.3"
    }
}
```

and in your android/app/build.gradle dependency, use this facebookSdkVersion as well

```
implementation "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:$facebookSdkVersion"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue today. I was using 'flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.0'

I upgraded it to `flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0`. I had to change `logInWithReadPermission` to `logIn` and it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I used this version [5,6)
 compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'

but I resolved below version 
 compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

Have a Good Day